# ser / deser using Jackson: Not able to write a single serdes class

Tags: json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a POJO which I am trying to ser/deser using Jackson.
However, I want the class to provide its own ser/deser logic. So I can write something like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyClass.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = MyClass.class)
class MyClass ... {

    private String x;
    private String y;

    // getters and setters

    void serialize(MyClass object, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
        SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            ....
    }

    MyClass deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            ....
    }
}
```

I do not want to write two classes to provide ser / deser logic per POJO that I define.

1. Can I use any kind of a proxy mechanism to achieve this, given that
   JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer are abstract classes and not interfaces?
2. Does this violate a good practice?

Initial research:

- Questions on stack overflow
- [This](http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html) discussion.

Comment: This is not OOP. You have to decouple POJO objects from the methods to serialize it. What if in the future, you will have to serialize it to XML or binary format? Will you implement serialization method in POJO class as well? Hmm, it does not look well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you can not make a class that implements two abstract classes. So you need two separate classes, if directly implementing these classes.

As to proxy: what is the benefit? Amount of functionality to write is the same; if there are commonalities, abstract them out to a utility class. So what is the actual problem you are solving? (assuming this is not just question of personal preference)